# Usando listas encadenadas, donde esta el error?

Tags: c++, lista

Saludos! Practicando listas encadenadas, no encuentro el error en el siguiente codigo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

struct newNode
{
    int info;
    struct newNode *link;
};

typedef struct newNode *nNode;

void addNode(nNode &list, int info)
{
    nNode new;
    new = new(struct newNode);
    new->info = info;
    new->link = list;
    list = new;
}

void printList(nNode list)
{
    int count = 0;

    while(list != NULL)
    {
        cout << "[" << list->info << "]->";
        list = list->link;
        count++;
    }

    cout << "The length of the List is: " << count << endl;
}

int main()
{
    nNode list = NULL;
    addNode(list, 1);
    addNode(list, 2);
    addNode(list, 3);
    addNode(list, 4);
    addNode(list, 5);
    printList(list);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ese código que muestras es **imposible** que compile. `new` es una **palabra reservada** de C++, que no se puede usar para variables. Por favor, editar tu código para que sirva como [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Y si dieras mas datos sobre tu problema específico (texto de error exacto, comportamiento esperado/obtenido), mejor. Piensa en futuros usuarios del sitio.

Comment: ¿Y cómo sabes que hay un error? Supongo que compilando el programa te habrá dado un error ¿Cuál ha sido ese error? ¿has intentado **leer y entender el error** mostrado? Si no lo entiendes comparte dicho error y te ayudamos.

Comment: Gracias! ya vi que era por la palabra reservada @Trauma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se pueden nombrar a las variables usando palabras reservadas, `new` en este caso:

```
void addNode(nNode &list, int info)
{
    nNode new;
    new = new(struct newNode);
    new->info = info;
    new->link = list;
    list = new;
}
```

Arreglando esto, el programa funciona perfectamente:

```
void addNode(nNode &list, int info)
{
    nNode nuevo;
    nuevo = new(struct newNode);
    nuevo->info = info;
    nuevo->link = list;
    list = nuevo;
}
```

Comment: Gracias. No encontraba el supuesto error. Solo era que la palabra 'new' es reservada para el lenguaje.